# Swift code to use AVWriter/AVReader to extract .wav audio from .mp4 video writing zero byte file

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I've gone through the documentation and all the posts here, and I've gotten this far.

The function below should take an AVAsset and write out a .wav file. However, the file written out is of zero bytes. I'm not sure I can even inspect what the writer is writing at each step.

What am I missing?

```
    static func writeAudioTrackToUrl(asset: AVAsset, _ url: URL) throws {
    // initialize asset reader, writer
    let assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
    let assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/audiowav.wav"), fileType: .wav)
    
    // get audio track
    let audioTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first!
    
    // configure output audio settings
    let audioSettings: [String : Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        AVSampleRateKey: 22050.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false
    ]
    let assetReaderAudioOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: audioTrack, outputSettings: audioSettings)
    
    if assetReader.canAdd(assetReaderAudioOutput) {
        assetReader.add(assetReaderAudioOutput)
    } else {
        fatalError("could not add audio output reader")
    }
    
    let inputAudioSettings: [String:Any] = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatLinearPCM]
    let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: inputAudioSettings, sourceFormatHint: (audioTrack.formatDescriptions[0] as! CMFormatDescription))
    
    let audioInputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audioQueue")
    assetWriter.add(audioInput)
    
    assetWriter.startWriting()
    assetReader.startReading()
    assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime.zero)
    
    audioInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: audioInputQueue) {
        while (audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
            let sample = assetReaderAudioOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
            if (sample != nil) {
                audioInput.append(sample!)
            } else {
                audioInput.markAsFinished()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    assetWriter.finishWriting {
                        assetReader.cancelReading()
                    }
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you convert the input audio to the LPCM format described by `audioSettings`, but then you give a `sourceFormatHint` of `audioTrack.formatDescriptions[0]` to the `AVAssetWriterInput`.

This is a problem because the audio track format descriptions are not going to be LPCM but a compressed format, like `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`.

Just drop the hint, I think it's for passing through compressed formats anyway.

Further, the LPCM in `inputAudioSettings` is under specified - why not pass `audioSettings` directly?

In summary, try this:

```
let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
```

p.s. don't forget to delete the output file before running, `AVAssetWriter` doesn't seem to overwrite existing files

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the explanation! That worked like a charm!